# Convert convert int to alphabetical value

Tags: c#, char, int

i would like to convert `int`'s between 1-26 to the corresponding alphabetical `char` letter

i saw somewhere i could use `char outPut = (char)currentValue;` or `Convert.ToChar(currentValue` however both do not seem to work. i am testing this by having the program print the char to the console. both attempts have resulted in a empty character being printed

i am making a program that takes in a `char` letter, converts it to an `int` to do some maths to it and then converts the final `int` back to a `char` letter and prints the `char` to the console

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
char outPut = (char)currentValue;
```

would give you a char that represents some whitespace character (since those are represented as integers up to 32.)

What you actually want is a char representing a *letter*. The following code will give you the ith letter of the alphabet in lowercase:

```
char c = (char)((int)'a' + i - 1);
```

Or in uppercase:

```
char c = (char)((int)'A' + i - 1);
```

It uses the fact that letters are represented by consecutive integers.

Answer (score 1):

You can offset by a character you want. In this case, I use `'a'`.

```
Console.WriteLine((char)(5 + 'a'));
```

As your range starts with `1`, you need to use `'a'-1`.

Comment: I know that this answer is just illustrating the technique, but I would still point out that since the integers in the question start at 1, the offset should in practice be `'a' - 1`.

Answer (score 0):

`int` and `char` can be converted back and forth by using the ASCII table

ASCII value for `A` is 65. So you can get char `A` by doing

```
char a = (char) 65;
```

to convert it back using the 1-26 representation just do

```
int num = a - 65 + 1;
```

You would need to do some boundary check to make sure the number is within range of course.

Comment: More relevantly, A is represented by the single UTF-16 code unit (`char`) with the integer value of 65. It would be quite a long story to go from the fundamentals of C# way back around to ASCII.